# Backbone.js collection fetch 'this._byId' undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, coffeescript, fetch

I'm using coffeescript.  My code is pretty simple:

```
class SomeCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  constructor: (@options) ->
  url: ->
    "#{$SCRIPT_ROOT}/some/data/#{@options.someId}"
  model: SomeModel

class SomeView extends Backbone.View
  initialize: ->
    myCollection = new SomeCollection()
    myCollection.fetch
      success: (coll, resp) ->
        console.log coll
```

The JSON that's being returned from my collection's url is exactly:

`[{"id": 1, "comments": "", "name": "images/exceptions/59.png"}]`

However, before anything is printed to the console, I receive a backbone.js error on **line 768**: *Cannot read property 1 of undefined*.  The undefined object is `this._byId` within the collection's `get` function.  How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are extending `Backbone.Collection` and providing your own constructor, so you need to make sure to call the parent constructor.

```
constructor: (@options) ->
  super null, @options
```

Also, the standard arguments for a Collection are `(models, options)`, so I would stick with that.

```
constructor: (models, @options) ->
  super models, @options
```

Or better yet, use `initialize` instead of `constructor` to avoid that entirely

```
initialize: (models, @options) ->
```

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks for your succinct yet complete explanation.